# put tcpdump in promiscuous mode and sniffing from any pc

Tags: tcpdump, traffic

At my home I use a wireless router to connect to internet, so every device uses wireless card to use it.

In this way using `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0` from my pc I should be able to see all the packets going around in the local net (thing that I couldn't do if everyone was connected using ethernet) and it looks it works.

Now I tryed `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 host 192.168.1.3` to see only the packets of a specific pc (which is not mine but of another different pc) but I get nothing just:

```
****@****-pc ~ $ sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 host 192.168.1.3
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

So I don't understand, why using `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0` I see everything but I can't say to just track one specific flow?

Comment: I'd rectify that not tcpdump do you put in promiscuous mode but the network card you order it to sniff through. What does `sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 | grep '192\.168\.1\.3'` yield?

Comment: Is your wireless router configured as "bridge" or as a "router"? The difference between one and the other is that, bridge will make all physical media as one(wireless and ethernet), and routing, you will be closed to a broadcast domain an you will probably not see packages coming from ethernet hosts.

Comment: @nwildner Bridge/router mode controls how packets are relayed between the LAN and WAN, it shouldn't affect LAN-LAN traffic. But if the router or access point acts as a switch, it won't reflect packets out to all interfaces.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Are you seeing traffic for other hosts or not?

Comment: @Barman. Some WiFi routers allow you to isolate L2 from Ethernet and Wireless connections and the dhcp on those will deliver different ip ranges. And yeah, I found this question a little confusing too...

Comment: Example using dd-wrt and independent bridges - http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Separate_LAN_and_WLAN

Answer (score 1):

Many wireless cards will refuse to be set to promiscuous mode. (There are exceptions but these are relatively rare.) Without seeing a text dump of your capture it's impossible to be sure, but it's likely that all you're seeing from your `tcpdump` is normal broadcast traffic. As a consequence, when you ask to see traffic for a particular host you will see nothing except its broadcast traffic, of which there should be very little.

Answer (score 0):

Because the NIC may filter out the packets which are not addressed to your pc by MAC address, and so may any routers the packet passes through. A WiFi Router is also a switch and/or a router (depending on configuration).

For information, a switch works on the link layer (2nd layer of OSI mode). Routers work on layer 3.